# Enabling disabled button after successful jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code where I have 2 email input fields which I need to validate they are the same which is working successfully using jQuery validate equalTo.

```
<div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail"><strong>Email Address</strong></label>
   <div class="controls">
    <input type="email" name="inputEmail" placeholder="jane.smith@email.com" id="inputEmail" required>
   </div>
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmailConfirm"><strong>Confirm Email Address</strong></label>
     <div class="controls">
    <input type="email" name="inputEmailConfirm" placeholder="jane.smith@email.com" id="inputEmailConfirm" required>
    </div>
    </div>
  <button type="submit" id="emailSubmit" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click me to buy">Credit Card Checkout &raquo; </button>
```

Upon successful validation I wish to enable the button, but can't seem to figure out how to do this.

```
 $('#ccSelectForm').validate({
    rules: {
      inputEmail: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      inputEmailConfirm: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        equalTo: '#inputEmail'
      },
    }
  });
```

Ideally as bonus I'd like to set the form controls to utilise the validation states in Bootstrap3, detailed here - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation

Fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/4wU5m/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no jQuery Validate plugin callback option/function that fires when all fields are valid without first clicking the submit button.

You'll need to create an external `keyup blur` event handler that checks your form for validity and enables/disables the button accordingly; every time a key is pressed or you leave a field.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/p628Y/1/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#ccSelectForm').validate({
        rules: {
            inputEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            inputEmailConfirm: {
                // required: true,  // <-- redundant
                // email: true,     // <-- redundant
                equalTo: '#inputEmail'
            }  // <-- removed trailing comma
        }
    });

    $('#ccSelectForm input').on('keyup blur', function () { // fires on every keyup & blur
        if ($('#ccSelectForm').valid()) {                   // checks form for validity
            $('button.btn').prop('disabled', false);        // enables button
        } else {
            $('button.btn').prop('disabled', 'disabled');   // disables button
        }
    });

});
```

Since the jQuery Validate plugin disables the browser's HTML5 validation dynamically, I removed the `required` attribute from your markup and changed `type="email"` into `type="text"`.  (*You already have these validation rules specified in the plugin*.)

```
<input type="text" name="inputEmail" placeholder="jane.smith@email.com" id="inputEmail" />
<input type="text" name="inputEmailConfirm" placeholder="jane.smith@email.com" id="inputEmailConfirm" />
```

You also don't need to specify all the rules twice when using the `equalTo` rule as the second field must already always match the first.

---

**EDIT:**

In the above scenario, your page is totally dependent upon JavaScript.  In other words, without JavaScript, the button is always disabled.

If you have server-side validation in place and want your page to be independent of JavaScript, you'll need to remove the `disabled="disabled"` from your button markup and add it to your JavaScript just inside the DOM ready event handler.

```
$('button.btn').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

In this scenario, without JavaScript, you'll still have a working button, and with JavaScript, the button is disabled programatically on page load.

Comment: +1 You answer is nice.But also keep a check if user paste using context menu.

Comment: @TusharGupta, Thank-you.  I'm in Firefox and my demo is also working with contextual paste and autocomplete.  However, I added the `blur` event just to be certain.

Comment: Welcome sir now it is perfect. I'm using Chrome .

Comment: This is great, thank you. The only thing is I've left the HTML5 `type="email"` as if Javascript is disabled as mentioned in your edit, I still have some validation happening, although I'm not sure of the impact of having both, but it seems to work.

Comment: @LJT, it won't hurt to have HTML5 validation in place along with jQuery Validate.  As I stated, the plugin will silently disable HTML5 validation.  However, the plugin does not fully support all HTML5 input `type` attributes, but `type="email"` is fine.

Comment: with this solution all the fields are having some error message after the first char I type.. I know this is just a detail, but isn't there another way we could have the "disable submit button" behavior without showing this bunch of error messages after the first char typed?

Comment: @FelipeMosso, your comment makes no sense... typing just one character in one field absolutely does not cause a bunch of error messages to show.  Please post a whole new question including all relevant code and details.

Comment: @Sparky, take a look at the fiddle you provided: http://jsfiddle.net/p628Y/1/

type one character in the first input field. For me, it shows two messages, one besides each field (password and confirm, even though I just interact with the first)

Comment: @FelipeMosso, I thought you were talking about a single field.  In this case, as you can see in the jsFiddle, there is a custom `keyup` and `blur` event handler that checks the entire form's validity before enabling or disabling the button.  You cannot check form validity of the form without having messages show up when the form is still invalid.

Comment: @Sparky yes.. I imagined that this wasn't possible.. I ended up always allowing the submit button but show a toast message if user clicks there when the form is still invalid... thanks anyway for returning back to this discussion :)

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant and fast solution is to simply override the default on-click and on-keyup events adding the code you need as follows instead of adding another listen event

```
$("#form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    },
    onkeyup: function( element, event ) {
        if ( event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "" ) {
            return;
        } else if ( element.name in this.submitted || element === this.lastElement ) {
            this.element(element);
        }

        this.checkForm();

        if (this.valid()) { // checks form for validity
            $('a.submit').attr('class', 'submit btn btn-success');        // enables button
        } else {
            $('a.submit').attr('class', 'submit btn btn-danger disabled');   // disables button
        }
    },
    onclick: function( element ) {
        // click on selects, radiobuttons and checkboxes
        if ( element.name in this.submitted ) {
            this.element(element);

        // or option elements, check parent select in that case
        } else if ( element.parentNode.name in this.submitted ) {
            this.element(element.parentNode);
        }

        this.checkForm();

        if (this.valid()) { // checks form for validity
            $('a.submit').attr('class', 'submit btn btn-success');        // enables button
        } else {
            $('a.submit').attr('class', 'submit btn btn-danger disabled');   // disables button
        }
    }
})
```

With the following css code for the submit trigger - initially disabled (bootstrap 3 classes):

```
<a onclick="if(!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) { $('#form').submit(); }" class="submit btn btn-danger disabled">button_save</a>
```

This can very easy be used with jquery plug-in [areYouSure](https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure) to only enable the submit when actual changes are made:

```
if (this.valid() && $('#form').hasClass('dirty')) { // checks form for validity
```

initializing the plug-in using silent:

```
$('#form').areYouSure( {'silent':true} );
```