# jquery function if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validation plugin to validate my form. The function below, displays errors under each field where the error is detected.

```
errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());

        }
    });
```

How can I evaluate if this function has been used "error has been displayed on screen" or not?

What I'm trying to is to evaluate if form has been validated or not, so I can perform other logic such as disabling submit button or changing button text to "please wait for example".

I'm not sure how I can go about doing that.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: What about making a Demo?

Comment: See:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/21953694/594235

Comment: I've answered a thousand questions about this plugin, but I've never seen anyone need to tell if an error has ever been generated when there is another method that will reliably tell you when the form is valid. You also have not clearly explained why you want to see if this particular callback has been fired.  We might be able to suggest a better way if we knew more about your specific requirements.  Exactly when do you want the button to be enabled and disabled?  Exactly when do you want to change the text of the button? etc?

Comment: The wording of the question remains ambiguous.  **Quote OP**:  _"What I'm trying to is to evaluate if form has been validated or not"_ ~ Does this mean you simply want to test the form to see if it's valid?  Or does it mean you want to see if it's ever been tested before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [submitHandler](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#toptions), as it is a **callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid**. So ,

```
$("#your-form").validate({
     .....
     submitHandler: function(){
        //form is valid 
        //do some logic
        $('#your_submit_btn_id').attr('disabled','disabled');
     },
    .....
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just set a boolean variable indicating that the method has been called:

```
hasError: false,
errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
    this.hasError = true
}
```

Then you can check the `hasError` whenever you need to. Be sure to store `hasError` on an object in order not to pollute the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can always handle submit event using this code:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    // some other code
    // maybe disabling submit button // $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
    // then:
    $(form).submit();
  }
 });
```

**`submitHandler` will only get called once form gets validated & there is no error.**

Documentation can be found here: http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look on this:

- http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/
- http://www.kianworknotes.com/2013/06/error-handling-in-jquery-validation.html

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g32qgr5v/1/)

```
/*error and element is parameter*/
errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 

  error.appendTo( element.parent("td").next("td") );

}
```

Comment: The OP already shows similar usage of the `errorPlacement` option, and it's not really what he's asking about.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function(){
    if($(this).valid()) //this returns true if the form is valid, and false if there is some validation error
    {
        //submit the form
    }
    else
    {
        //disable the submit button or change text as desired
        return false; //to avoid form submission
    }

});
```