# jQuery Validate plugin, enable submit button when form is valid

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have an enabled and disabled state for the submit button on my form.

The conditions are as follows:

If all input fields have been entered and are **valid** enable the submit button.

If **some** fields have not been entered do not enable the submit button.

So far the validation is being done within the onkeyup event and is only working for the first input:

```
//Custom onkeyup validation
            onkeyup: function(element) {
                //Check if input is empty remove valid class from parent
                var formInput = $(element),
                    formInputParent = $(element).parent('fieldset');
                if(formInputParent.hasClass('form--valid') && formInput.val() === "") {
                    formInputParent.removeClass('form--valid');
                }

                //Check if all fields are not empty to remove submit--disabled class
                var formInputs = $('form').find(':input');
                console.log(formInputs);

                formInputs.each(function(){
                    if(formInputs.length > 0) {
                        formInputs.parents('form').find('.submit-form').removeClass('submit--disabled');
                    } 
                });

            }
```

Check here for a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/89y26/328/)

Comment: Duplicate of this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21956309/594235

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You would simply construct a `blur` (or even a `keyup`) handler function to toggle the button based on the form's validity.  Use the plugin's `.valid()` method to test the form.

```
$('input').on('blur', function() {
    if ($("#myform").valid()) {
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);  
    } else {
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/sd88wucL/**

---

Instead, you could also use *both* events to trigger the same handler function...

```
$('input').on('blur keyup', function() {
    if ($("#myform").valid()) {
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);  
    } else {
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

**DEMO 2: http://jsfiddle.net/sd88wucL/1/**

**Source:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21956309/594235**

Comment: Sparky, although this is great - this validation triggers all form fields on the page once you 'blur' from one input. Is it possible to validate only each input as you go?

Comment: @Filth, yes and no.  Yes, you can attach `.valid()` to the individual fields within the `onfocusout` handler.  However, for activating your `submit` button, you cannot invoke `.valid()` to return a boolean without also invoking the error messages... `.valid()` does both at the same time.  No method is provided that can tell you if the form is valid without also activating validation on the form.

Comment: That's exactly the issue I'm having. I've tried adding the blur function to the onfocusout but that disabled the validation I have for the unhighlight / highlight functions for adding and removing valid / error classes. Is there any workaround I can do to achieve this? I have tried setting up custom functions to check all inputs for error messages to then enable the submit button but with no luck...

Comment: @Filth, I've answered over a thousand jQuery Validate questions and probably read all 4700 questions on SO... and I know of nothing that can tell you the form is valid without also triggering the validation messages.  If you write your own custom function for this, then you wouldn't need the plugin because you'd essentially be writing client-side validation from scratch.  Maybe you can restrict the handler above to only fire when no fields are left blank... it's not perfect.

Comment: You definitely are a whizz when it comes to jQuery Validate no doubt! Thanks for your time.

Comment: I just wonder why there is no event fired when the form becomes valid/invalid. Using blur/keyup sounds bit odd to me.

Comment: @SkorunkaFrantišek, the developer has not provided any event that fires on a valid form.  However, the `blur` and `keyup` events normally fire the validation test, so you can also use these to trigger a validation test and activate the button.

Comment: @Sparky You are a genius! I was desperately trying to find something in the validate plugin like a validateChangeHandler. This one works like magic.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The code below is what I ended up with so far:

```
$('#formId').on('blur keyup change', 'input', function(event) {
  validateForm('#formId');
});

function validateForm(id) {
  var valid = $(id).validate().checkForm();
    if (valid) {
      $('.form-save').prop('disabled', false);
        $('.form-save').removeClass('isDisabled');
    } else {
      $('.form-save').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.form-save').addClass('isDisabled');
    }
}

// Run once, so subsequent input will be show error message upon validation
validateForm('#formId');
```

It uses `checkForm()` instead of the `form()` and my disable button has the class`form-save`

It is based on [@Sparky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27050178/3163075)

There is an [issue filed on the jquery-validation git repo](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues/1996).

Comment: This was the only solution that worked, the accepted answer will trigger validation feedback for all the inputs as soon as you start typing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').find(':input').each(function(index, value){
    //action for every element
    $(value);
});
```

In this case you can do this that way: (but I dont like this solution)

```
var areSomeFieldsEmpty = false;
$('form').find(':input').each(function(i, v){
  if ($(v).val().length <= 0){
     areSomeFieldsEmpty = true;
  }
});

if (!areSomeFieldsEmpty){
  //unlock form   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/89y26/335/

Answer (score 0):

```
  <html>
     <form id="form">
     name<br>
     <input type="text"><br>
     Roll Number<br>
     <input type="number"><br>
     <input id="next" type="submit" disabled="disabled">
     </form>
  </html>
```

Initially, I have set submit button disabled and for each change in the input tag I will call a function to validate the form using jquery

```
  $("input[type='text'], input[type='number']").on("input", function () {       
   validate();
  });

  function validate(){  
    var show = true;  
    $("input[type='text'], input[type='number']").each(function(){
      if($(this).val()==''){
          show = false;
      }
    });

    if(show){
      $('#next').css({cursor:'pointer'})
      $('#next').removeAttr('disabled')
    }
    else {
      $('#next').css({cursor:'not-allowed'})
    }
  }
});
```